# How can I get a picture of a user who is not registered as a tester in the instagram basic API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, bubble.io

I'm a developer of 'Bubble.io(no-code tool)', and I'd like to use the instagram basic API to get a photo of a user who isn't registered as a tester.

I want the ability for users to log into their Instagram (certified) and share their Instagram feed with others.

I bring pictures of accounts that are currently registered as testers, but I can't access accounts that aren't registered as testers.

Can I get someone else's photo through instagram basic API?

I connected the Instagram basic API.
The document was referred to the following link.
[text](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api)

There is no problem with receiving access tokens or changing them to long-term tokens,etc.
I'm just looking for a way to link data from accounts that I haven't registered as a tester.

When I log in with an account that I haven't registered as a tester, it comes back to redirect uri page well, but the photo doesn't load. (I think it's because I don't have permission)